# How do I run Commands with Elevated Privileges in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, forms-authentication, wss-3.0

I'm using forms authentication to log in into windows sharepoint servevices 3.0 service.
I need to elevate during anonymous access, rights to add record to sharepoint portal list.

I found clue in msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466220%28classic%29.aspx

But it doesn't work for me. :( It's still calling for user login and password.

Can anybody help me please?

```
Public Function AddUserAccountData() As String
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(AddressOf AddUserAccountDataToSPList)
        Return ""
    End Function

    Private Sub AddUserAccountDataToSPList()
        Dim oSharedConfig As SharedConfig = SharedConfig.Instance
        Dim sListName As String = oSharedConfig.oWebPartsOpt.UserOpt.AccountVerificationList.Name

        Using oSite As SPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web
            Dim oUserAccStatusList As SPList = oSite.Lists(sListName)

            oUserAccStatusList.Items.Add()
            Dim oSPListItem As SPListItem = oUserAccStatusList.Items.Add()

            oSPListItem("one") = _sUserLogin
            oSPListItem("two") = _sUserGuid
            oSPListItem("three") = False
            oSPListItem("four") = DateTime.Now

            oSPListItem.Update()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Are you still getting **Access Denied**, or some other error? (if you're POSTing data, SharePoint will throw another exception, for example, and there are many other cases). Can you post the code that calls `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, opens the site and adds the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` you shouldn't use `SPContext.Current` - it still has the old permissions. You should reopen your `SPWeb` to give it the right permissions. On your linked code this is done by the lines:

```
using (SPSite ElevatedsiteColl = new SPSite(siteColl.ID))
using (SPWeb ElevatedSite = ElevatedsiteColl.OpenWeb(site.ID))
```

Source:
[RunWithElevatedPrivileges, watch out for the site context](http://www.mikhaildikov.com/2007/07/runwithelevatedprivileges-watch-out-for.html)
[Adding Items to a SharePoint List](http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/adding-items-to-a-sharepoint-list/) - from my blog, might help with your next problem.

Another note: you should not be writing `Using oSite As SPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web`. `SPContext` objects should not be disposed by you - they are shared between different components, so it may lead to other exceptions.
This is a common mistake - it could have been done better by the API in my opinion.

Comment: The answer is on your blog here: http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/adding-items-to-a-sharepoint-list/

The key for the last error was setting up flag: AllowUnsafeUpdates

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
oUserAccStatusList.Items.Add()
```

Looks a little off. Once you have a reference to the SPList you create a new `listItem` like you have in the following code, by calling the `Items.Add` on the `listItem`, set your properties and then call the `Update` method.